# Посчитать количество предложений в тексте

Tags: java, текст, семантика, nlp, лексический-анализатор

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста решение моей проблемы.  Я пытаюсь сделать так, что из текста, который считывается с файла, я получаю количество предложений. Это в моем коде работает. Но! я не понимаю как расширить программу, чтобы учесть, что точка не всегда обозначает окончание предложения. Точка также может использоваться в качестве сокращений, например и.о.(исполняющий обязаности).

```
package ir_ub2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.ReadOnlyFileSystemException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class TextCounts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // datei lesen
        FileReader fileName = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Olga\\Desktop\\ub_2\\inputDE.txt");

        // wrap a BufferedReader around FileReader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileName);
        int sentenceCount = 0;
        String line;
        String terminalSymbol = ".?!";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // Continue reading until end    of file is reached
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if (terminalSymbol.indexOf(line.charAt(i)) != -1) { // If the delimiters string contains the character
            sentenceCount++;
            }
        }
    }


    reader.close();
    System.out.println("The number of sentences is " + sentenceCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Думаю, без семантического анализа, никак не определить. Как отличить `ув. Иванов` от `конец предложения. Начало следующего`. Только если ввести список всех возможных сокращений.

Comment: andy.37, согласна, как мне это сделать? Вы бы не могли мне помочь? Я тольео вторую неделю изучаю java и у меня еще сплошные пробелы в теории :(

Comment: 1) я не знаю java (от слова совсем). 2) Вы представляете себе объем  работы при написании семантического анализатора произвольного текста? Это задача на годы.

Comment: Дааа прям таки "задача на годы". Вы решили тут пофилософствовать. На знаете как помочь, то не надо тратить время на формулировку неконстуктивных ответов.

Comment: Если вы так будете писать каждому, кто оставит свой коментарий, боюсь что Вам не помогут с ответом

Comment: Все же поробую дать совет. Разделитель предложений - не просто `.!?`, а один из этих символов, после которых обязательно идет один или более пробельных символов, после котрых идет заглавная буква или цифра. Останется проблема с инициалами, ну можно попробовать что-то вроде  незаглавной буквы перед точкой. С реализацией, сорри, не помогу, т.к. повторюсь - Java не знаю. Регулярка в стиле перл будет выглядеть примерно так: `[^A-Z][.!?]\s+[A-Z]`

Comment: andy.37, спасибо. Прошу извинения, если мой пост был резким.

Comment: @OlgaM извинения приняты)

Comment: Вопрос здесь не в том, сколько дней или лет вы учите тот или иной язык, вопрос в том, что вам реально нужно обучить программу понимать текст. Конкретный язык программирования тут не при чём, это вопрос теории. Вы **не можете** по-лёгкому, на основе формальных критериев, отличить конец предложения от сокращения. Сравните, например: «В дуэли участвовали г. Пушкин и г. Дантес» и «Мои стихи — одно сплошное г. Пушкин бы застрелился, но не стал читать такое.»

Comment: Возможно стоить учесть, что первое слово следующего предложения начинается с буквы. Ну и я бы посоветовал создать базу сокращений для проверки.

Comment: Как вы думаете, сколько предложений в этом тексте: 多少你想在這個文本的建議？

Answer (score 23):

Рискуя навлечь на себя гнев всей ленты все таки напишу:

> А вы, друзья, как ни садитесь,
>   Все в музыканты не годитесь

Ну если серьезно, то не надо кустарщину, а надо решить задачу по правильному.

Я вижу 2 возможных способа:

1. Либо засунуть ваш текст в [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming) сеть и обучить ее. Для начала можно взять [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) и попробовать обучить ее.
2. Взять [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) и попробовать [SentenceTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-smartcn/org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/SentenceTokenizer.html) - который разобьет текст на предложения. Lucene, [насколько я понимаю, поддерживает русский язык](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ru/RussianAnalyzer.html), есть кстати и внешние расширители [Lucene для русской морфологии](https://github.com/akuznetsov/russianmorphology)

Как то так.

Comment: Случилось **соловью** на шум их прилететь?

Answer (score 11):

с такими, различного рода, сокращениями (и.о., т.н., И.С. Тургенев ...). Стоит учитывать количество символов, между точками, либо количество символов до точки. Таких коротких предложений не бывает, следовательно их можно не учитывать. Также можно заложиться на предложения вроде: "Да.", "Нет." Не думаю что таких коротких очень много наберется.

В любом случае, задача бесполезная, имхо.

Comment: snowhead почему же бесполезная задача. На 100% используется в Information Retrieval.

Comment: почему таких коротких предложение не бывает? А? :-D

Answer (score 11):

Навскидку несколько моментов, которые казалось бы простую задачу превращают в нерешаемую:

1. [Парцелляция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)) - не понятно, это одно предложение или все-таки несколько:

   *Он тоже пошёл. В магазин. Купить сигарет. (Шукшин)*
2. Предложения с прямой речью:

   *Игнат прошептал: "Да ну эту задачу к черту," - и нервно засмеялся.*
3. Ошибки сканирования, опечатки, отсутствие знаков препинания как в типичном интернет-общении. При включенном капсе границы предложения не маркированны никак.

   *ВЕДЬ ВСЕ БЫЛО ТАК ПРОСТО ЕЩЕ ПЯТЬ МИНУТ НАЗАД НЕНАВИЖУ*
4. Вкрапления кода:

   *Для вывода имени пользователя наберите*
   echo $name . ' ' . $surname.

Answer (score 8):

Это открытая научная задача.

[Тут](http://opennlp.apache.org/), например люди пытаются ее как-то решить.

Есть [библиотека для Питона](http://www.nltk.org/), которая с этой задачей неплохо справляется(как минимум для английского). Если использовать Яву все-таки очень нужно, см. Jython.

Answer (score 6):

Можно использовать regex:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\.\s*[A-ZА-Я]").matcher(yourText); //Вместо yourText должна быть переменная с текстом, в котором нужно посчитать предложения
int count = 1;
while(m.find()) count++; //Будут сосчитаны все предложения начинающиеся с большой буквы
```

Answer (score 0):

Cвой вопрос мне удалось решить. Для тех, кому интерессно вот мой ответ. Стоит отметить, что задание было для текстов немецкого языка и случаи с сокращением инициалов имени (напр.А.С. Пушкин) учитывать мне не нужно было.

```
package ir_ub2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TextCounts {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader file = new FileReader("inputDE.txt"); // datei lesen

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        int sentenceCount = 0;
        String line;
        String delimiter = ".?!";
        String[] singlePointExceptions = {
            "19. Jahrhundert", "allg.", "bzw.", "bspw.", "etc.", "evtl.", "geb.", "ggf.", "n.Chr", "od.", "s.", "u.", "usw.", "vgl."
        };
        String[] doublePointExceptions = {
            "b.w.", "d.h.", "d.i", "n.Chr.", "s.a.", "s.o.", "s.u.", "u.a.", "u.Ä.", "u.U.", "u.z.", "v.a.", "v.Chr.", "z.B.", "z.T.", "z.Zt."
        };

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { // Continue reading until end of file is reached
            int countQuestionsAndExclamations = countMatchesOfSpecialCharacters(line, "?", "!");
            int countSingles = countMatchesOfSpecialCharacters(line, singlePointExceptions);
            int countDoubles = countMatchesOfSpecialCharacters(line, doublePointExceptions);
            int countPoints = countMatchesOfSpecialCharacters(line, ".");

            sentenceCount += (countQuestionsAndExclamations + (countPoints - (countSingles + countDoubles)));
        }

        reader.close();
        file.close();
        System.out.println("# of founded Sentences: " + sentenceCount);

    }

    private static int countMatchesOfSpecialCharacters(final String str, final String...specialCharacters) {
        if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (null == specialCharacters || specialCharacters.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < specialCharacters.length; i++) {
            String special = specialCharacters[i];
            index = 0;
            while ((index = str.indexOf(special, index)) != -1) {
                count++;
                index += special.length();
                if (index >= str.length()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что с 20. Jahrhundert, или, боже упаси, 21.? А если »z. B.« напишут с пробелом?

Comment: Согласна, что мой вариант не идеален. Каюсь уже, что выставила. Если бы я в соем вопросе указала, что мне для немецкого языка нужно, то вряд ли бы я получила какие либо ответы.

Comment: @Igor: Если текст _конкретный_, то правильным решением было бы что-то наподобие `System.out.println(20);`

Answer (score 0):

Вот написал, по моему получилось интересно. Данный код понимает такой вид тестовых предложений.

```
Привет тест. T..... a Тестирование 34. WHAT???
```

Вывод

`Предложений по моему мнению:4`

Также есть дебаг фитчи для теста, он после каждого предложения выводит само предложение. Их можно удалить, а можно использовать.

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Привет тест. T..... a Тестирование 34. WHAT???";

        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
        byte tocka = '.'; //заставляем интерпретатор из символа точки получить 1 байт(можно цифру, но так понятнее вам будет)
        byte vopr = '?';
        byte voscl = '!';

        int count = 0; //храним количество
        int max = bytes.length;
        if(max>0){
            int i = 0; //сдвиг

            byte a; //активный байт


            //ДЕБАГ, В СЛУЧАЕ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ СКРИПТА БЕЗ ДЕБАГА ЗАКОМЕНТИТЬ ОТ И ДО
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //буфер для предложений
            //дебаг режим выводит уже предложения

            //РАЗБИРАЕМ
            while(i<max){ //ЦИКЛ ОСНОВА
                while(i<max){ //ЦИКЛ ПРЕРЫВАЕТСЯ ОЗНАЧАЮЩИЙ КОНЕЦ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ
                    a = bytes[i];
                    i = i + 1;

                    if(i<max){ //ЕСТЬ СИМВОЛЫ ДЛЯ ДЕБАГИНГА
                        if(a == tocka || a == vopr || a == voscl){ //ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ.
                            //проверяем следующий символ
                            a = bytes[i];
                            i = i + 1;
                            if(i<max){
                                if(a == tocka || a == vopr || a == voscl){ //возможно это троеточие, почемубы и нет? или ???:)
                                    while(i<max){
                                        a = bytes[i];
                                        if(a!=tocka && a!=vopr && a!=voscl){
                                            break;
                                        }
                                        i = i + 1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //ДЕБАГ
                        out.write(a);
                    //
                }
                count = count + 1; //ПРЕРЫВАНИЕ БЫЛО ИЛИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ ОКОНЧЕНО ЗНАЧИТ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ

                //ДЕБАГ, МОЖНО ЗАКОМЕНТИТЬ
                  System.err.println(out.toString());
                  out.reset();
                //
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Предложений по моему мнению:"+String.valueOf(count));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь воспользоваться функцией String.split(".");
Функция вернёт массив предложений, а с `predlidzenja.length()` можно получить длину массива.

Comment: Как вы читаете вопрос? Автор говорит: ***"чтобы учесть, что точка не всегда обозначает окончание предложения. Точка также может использоваться в качестве сокращений, например и.о.(исполняющий обязанности)."***