# Разбираем Строки в C#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, хочу сделать программу, которая считывает текст с файла и выводит на экран только те предложения, что складываются из заданного количества слов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;


namespace Stroki
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] NewFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"полный адрес файла");


            foreach (string str in NewFile)//считывает весь файл?
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);//вывело строки файла

            }


       Console.Write("Введите количество слов = ");
       string buf = Console.ReadLine();
       int n = int.Parse(buf);

//тут фором пробегаемся посимвольно по строкам и находим разделительные знаки или пробелы.count++

//условие(если count в строке равен указаному вначале n,то выводим необходимое предложение или несколько,если они одинаковы по количеству слов в предложении)

         Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Пример файла:

```
Корова,мясо,трава,луга.  
Экзамены,зачёты,курсовые.   
Лето,зима.
```

P.S. Что если все предложения в одну строку?

Comment: "строка" != "предложение"

Comment: А если каждое предложение с новой строки?

Comment: Ну это «если». Если такое предположение выполняется, добавьте его в вопрос.

Comment: Потому что в общем случае разбиение текста на предложения AI-complete.

Comment: Для случая разбиения строки на слова, возникает вопрос, что есть слово. Если часть текста, ограниченная пробелами, и содержащая хотя бы одну букву — то `string.Split` вам в помощь.

Comment: @VladD, а в чём сложность разбиения на предложения? В русском языке  предложения оканчиваются вполне конкретными знаками, коих конечное количество и они известны. Поэтому разбить текст на предложения, как мне кажется, довольно просто.

Comment: @ixSci: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464257/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/465937#comment513322_464257

Comment: @VladD, добавляем словарь русских слов и в подавляющем большинстве случаев определяем конец предложения правильно.

Comment: @ixSci: А чем словарь поможет? Ну и «в большинстве случаев правильно» означает частичное решение. Представьте себе функцию, определяющую длину массива _в большинстве случаев_ правильно — вы ведь не станете ей пользоваться?

Comment: @VladD, это зависит от задачи. *Правильный* русский текст анализировать не так сложно, в примере, который Вы привели выше, используется неправильное написание слова «говно». Всё зависит от задачи, для многих задач «понимания» текста не требуется.

Comment: @ixSci: Сокращение «г.» может вполне означать, например, «год». «Дата дуэли — 27 января 1837 г.»

Comment: @VladD, согласен, но тогда должно быть 2 точки, если это конец предложения, так?

Comment: @VladD, забавно, в интернете считают, что точка будет только одна(что логично) и ссылаются на Розенталя, но у меня бумажная книга Розенталя издания 2012 года и там такого правила нет. Но будем считать, что точка должна быть одна. В таком случае — да, ситуация становится на порядок сложнее, т.к. в данном случае распознать предложения может быть весьма сложно(даже человеку).

Comment: @ixSci: Логически да, две точки было бы правильнее. Ещё лучше точку-сокращение представлять другим символом. Но язык, к сожалению, гадкая вещь. Правило насчёт одной точки мне вроде бы рассказывали в школе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дабы не грузить память, лучше воспользоваться классом StreamReader и считывать построчно. Дальше, сначала методом Split, разбиваете полученную строку по точкам, восклицательным знакам и т.п.

```
line.Split(".!?".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Массив предложений делите по пробелам и знакам препинания

```
int count = sentence.Split(" .,:;".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
```

Ну а дальше думаю будет понятно

Answer (score 1):

Как уже выше в комментариях отметили, вам надо использовать метод Split класса String для разбиения текста на части, которые являются предложениями. Для этого в метод Split можно передать знаки препинания, которыми оканчивается предложение. Дальше для каждого отдельного предложения подсчитать длину