# Разобрать текст на составные части?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .net

Примерно из такого текста:

> “We’re word word: word word. The word we can word the word, the word be,” word Name word—a word word to the W.W. Word Word Word—in word to Word. Word word word word.

надо выделить предложения, а из предложений надо выделить цитаты и названия.
Такое вообще возможно или нет?   Ну если кто-то меня обрадует, то будьте добры и подскажите как это сделать?

Решение не обязательно должно быть на основе регулярных выражений. Если есть какой-то другой способ, то он тоже подойдет.

Comment: Хорошая задача для спецкурса. Вам в сторону нейронных сетей или какой-то другой серьёзной эвристики.

Comment: Если и возможно регулярками, то не ранее, чем вы человеческими словами опишите _точные_ правила выделения каждой категории. Регулярка не до чего не додумается, ей нужен точно сформулированный критерий

Comment: Нейросети, глубокое обучение, big data и остальные buzzwords ни о чем не говорят. Мне нужны "имена, явки, пароли", то есть что-то конретное, что можно использовать.

Comment: Тут описывать нечего. Есть тексты, их надо разобрать на части, о которых сказано в вопросе. Ничего другого не надо.

Comment: уже было http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464257/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможно. Предложения разделяются точкой. Цитаты и названия выделены кавычками. Текст можно разобрать зная эти факты.

Подводные камни, которые я вижу:

1. Цитаты могут содержть предложения
2. Непонятно как разделить цитаты и названия. Возможно по длине, либо еще как.

Если принять некоторые упрощения, то задача решается обычными строковыми функциями.

Если же надо делать сложнее - то тут уже надо делать лексический разбор, на основе конечных автоматов, к примеру.

Comment: Если предложения делить по точкам, то из-за W.W. парсер предложений выдаст неправильный результат.

Comment: @Nunu я не знаю специфики вашей задачи. Ваш пример обходиться тем что на предложения делим не просто по точке, а по точке и обязательному пробелу после нее. Обычно такие задачи решаются по методу "снежного кома". Т.е. реализуется простейщий алгоритм - тестируется. Находятся слабые места и исправляются или обходятся. И опять тестируются. И так до получения удовлетворительного результата. В теории же можно долго размышлять...

Comment: На основе конечных автоматов - это как? Есть пример?

Comment: Про конечные автоматы это долго и нудно. Если на пальцах, то алгоритм считывает входные данные посимвольно и на основе этого определяет в каком состоянии он находится. Но при этом определение состояния зависит от того в каком предыдущем состоянии мы находились. Примера нет. Это больше из разработки комплияторов - там строится грамматика языка, потом по ней создается алгоритм такого конечного алгоритма и уже потом он программно реализуется.