# Разбить строку при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, нужно сформировать массив объектов StringBuilder из тех  предложений, в которых больше двух слов. Разделителями предложений считать ! ? точку и любую комбинацию этих символов. Разделителями слов считать пробел.

Подскажите, как разбить эту строку при помощи регулярного выражения? и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Добро пожаловать в чудесный мир семантического анализа текстов! Похожие вопросы задавились здесь много раз (и кажется не нашли полного ответа). Почитайте, например, [это обсуждение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464257/10105).

Comment: Немного не то, что хотелось бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так можно вывести все искомые предложения на консоль:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?'sentence'(\w+\s+){2,}\w+[.!?]+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match m in rx.Matches(s))
{
    string sentence = m.Groups["sentence"].Captures[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(sentence);
}
```

Но, насколько я понимаю, дело усложняется тем, что в каждом предложении могут быть ещё знаки препинания (какие?), а они не буквы.. Для запятой, двоеточия и точки с запятой шаблон может быть такой:

```
(?'sentence'(\w+[,:;]?\s+){2,}\w+[.!?]+)
```

Если же ещё принять во внимание, что некоторые слова разделяются дефисом, то шаблон усложняется:

```
(?'sentence'(\w+(\-\w+)?[,:;]?\s+){2,}\w+(\-\w+)?[.!?]+)
```

Учтём ещё, что в диалогах предложения могут начинаться с тире, и тире может быть и в середине предложений:

```
(?'sentence'((\-\s+)?\w+(\-\w+)?[,:;]?\s+){2,}(\-\s+)?\w+(\-\w+)?[.!?]+)
```

Мы ещё не учли слова в кавычках (и прямую речь), ошибки пунктуации (пробелы перед/после дефиса и перед знаками препинания) и т.п. Мне кажется, если задача частная (какой-то один текст), то можно попробовать допилить шаблон. Например, вместо `\w` брать `\S` (не пробел).

Если же задача общая, лучше поискать какую-нибудь специализированную библиотеку для разбора естественноязыковых текстов.

Comment: Для отладки регексов лучше пользоваться специальными сайтами, где регекс можно попробовать онлайн (просто поищите что-нибудь типа `regex online` или `regex online c#`) или прогами (RegExBuilder, Expresso, etc.). Можно и LINQPad использовать.

Comment: Интересный способ, попробую, я решил задачу, таким вот способом, насколько он верен?

Comment: `string rv1 = @"[!?.]", s1 = "Тут любой нужный нам текст";
Console.WriteLine("\n\nOriginal String: {0}", s1);
Regex R1 = new Regex(rv1);
string[] s2 = R1.Split(s1);
 //шаблон для откидывания предложения с одним словом
            string rv2 = @"\w+\s\w+";
            Regex R2 = new Regex(rv2);
            foreach (string ss in s2)
            {
                if (R2.IsMatch(ss)==true) //проверяем, из сколько слов состоит предложение
                Console.WriteLine(ss); 
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
`

Comment: Сори, что код весь в кашу, не знаю, как тут его порядок привести, что бы по строкам был =\

Comment: По строкам в комментах нельзя; можно добавить в сам вопрос.
Если задача решена, значит способ верен) Имейте ввиду, что `s2` не будет включать окончание предложения. Вместо  `R1.Split(s1)` наверное проще просто `s1.Split('!', '?', '.')`. В `rv2` `\s` лучше с плюсом: `\s+`, а то вдруг пробелов несколько.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySwsf5