# Токенизация текста

Tags: java, парсер, текст

Я пытаюсь сделать токенизатор текста.
Типа из такого текста:

```
10 meters 192.168.0.1 100
```

Он должен сделать такой массив (примерно):

```
[
    {
        type: "units:meters",
        value: "10"
    },
    {
        type: "ipaddress",
        value: "192.168.0.1"
    },
    {
        type: "number",
        value: "100"
    }
]
```

Я уже сделал отдельные парсеры для них, но они парсят весь текст и выдают все совпадения.

Как мне сделать, что-бы они были в правильном порядке и что-бы они не перекрывали друг-друга (например что-бы парсер начало и конец IP адреса не воспринимал отдельно как числа) ?

Comment: Отлично, и в чем же вопрос, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Kromster, прочитай конец вопроса

Comment: Конец **вопроса** заканчивается знаком `?`.

Comment: @Other, упс, забыл что я задаю вопрос =D

Comment: Пишем на русском, а правила не соблюдаем. Пробуйте регуляркой или брать сначала один символ, проверять на возможный токен, нет - берём ещё один и т. д.

Comment: @Other, оно у меня регулярками и сделано, но для каждого типа - разное регулярное выражение

Comment: Ну вот. Никто не сказал что нужно 2 раза универсальную регулярку применить и всё ОК. Хотя... Собрать все в одну и возвращать именованные группы.... Да, это идея, один раз скомпилировать регулярку и потом одной ею и проверять новый набор символов.

Comment: Токенизация реального текста — очень непростая задача. [Сложно даже точку как конец предложения отличить от точки, используемой для сокращения.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464257/10105)

Comment: @NeoKat В вашем вопросе не сформулировано, в чем конкретно вопрос и проблема. 1. Вам нужно решение в общем виде, как парсить строки? 2. Вам нужен конкретный "костыль" для конкретного описанного случая ? 3. Вам нужно отладить ваш уже написанный код? P.S. При чем тут метка "естественный-язык" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашёл решение:
Можно просто искать по одному парсерами и удалять пройденный кусок строки.