# Как правильно поделить строку на предложения?

Tags: c#, nlp

Есть строка

> Страна - производитель: Словакия Сейф HT 17/43 может быть установлен и
>   закреплен в мебель, между полками, т.к. только эта модель имеет
>   нестандартные габариты для сейфов (глубина и ширина сейфа в 2-2.5 раза
>   превышает высоту). Такое соотношение сторон наиболее удобно для
>   монтажа в мебель. В этом случае отведенное под сейф место используется
>   максимально. Сейф оборудован ключами аварийного доступа
>   (Mauer–Германия, Borg-Англия), исключающий блокировку электронного
>   замка при потере кода.

Я делал сперва так

```
var lst = str.Split('.').ToList();
```

Все в принципе правильно, однако когда есть слова `т.к` или 2.5 раза - то семантически неправильно предложение делится на строки. Как быть в таких случаях? Как семантически правильно поделить строки на предложения?

Comment: Можете сделать `Split('. ')`, но это плохой совет. Смотрите в сторону регулярных выражений.

Comment: Посмотрите сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/464257/10105

Answer (score 5):

Воспользоваться правилами русского языка? :) Базовый список такой:

1. Предложение заканчивается на `.`, `?`, `!`.
2. После знака следует пробел или перенос строки.
3. После пробела/переноса строки следует заглавная буква.

В зависимости от текста (например, если присутствуют списки или прямая речь) этот список может быть дополнен. Предлагаю сперва воспользоваться тремя приведенными правилами, а дальше при необходимости дополнить список. Результат он даст получше, однако на инициалах ("А. С. Пушкин") уже начнет лажать.

В общем виде, конечно, задача сложная и алгоритмом "на коленке" не обойдешься. Например, если текст сложный: `Как писал А. С. Пушкин: «Я помню чудное мгновенье. Ты съела всё моё варенье!» — своей няне в Шушенское из Ясной Поляны...` (спасибо @VladD за пример).

Comment: С нашим "Великим и могучим" вообще сложно. Структура предложений практически не поддается формализации и к большинству, если не всем, правилам можно подобрать контрпример из литературных источников. И это не учитывая, в среднем, низкой грамотности большинства текстов (особенно в рекламе бесит, мало того что реклама, так еще и с ошибками), где можно найти не только отсутствие положенных знаков препинания, но и вообще что угодно =)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться вот этим парсером:

https://tech.yandex.ru/tomita/

Но его придется обучить.

Answer (score -2):

```
var lst = str.Split('. ').ToList();
```

После предложений принято ставить пробел.

Comment: `Как насчет такого текста? Он ведь не разобьется.`

Comment: `Как писал А. С. Пушкин: «Я помню чудное мгновенье. Ты съела всё моё варенье!» — своей няне в Шушенское из Ясной Поляны...`

Comment: var lst = str.Split(new Char[] {'. ', '? ', '! '});

Comment: @VladD ну хорош шокировать :). Я кстати уже и не вспомню, этот пассаж считается одним предложением или нет :Р.

Comment: @Tomas, Не взлетит.

Comment: @s8am, то есть?

Comment: @andreycha: Вроде должен, но 100% не дам. Там ещё «А. С.», которые надо как-то учитывать.

Comment: @Tomas, Не будет такое корректно работать, выше Вам предоставили хороший контрпример.